# IDLE doesn't start in python 3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

If I have no connection to internet, does that mean I can't start **IDLE** (which comes with **python 3.0**)?

Comment: This question isn't really programming.  This is either a support issue, or a complaint.  Check the StackOverflow FAQ's http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Answer (score 6):

IDLE displays a warning message about firewall programs because it connects to the interpreter over the loopback interface, but that interface is always "connected" and doesn't require you to be on the Internet.

If IDLE isn't working for you with Python 3.0, you might consult [Python issue3628](http://bugs.python.org/issue3628).

Answer (score 0):

IDLE does not need to be connected to the internet.

Consult python support if you have problems: [Python help page](http://www.python.org/about/help/)

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You can download the latest version of Python 3.x suitable for whichever operating system you are using, and you can load IDLE without any internet.